# Why jdbc logs isn't working

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I try to activate JDBC logs into wildfly:

I added to my standalone.xml in subsystem "urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0":

```
<logger category="jboss.jdbc.spy">
    <level name="TRACE"/>
</logger>
```

and in my datasource statement : spy="true"

But, I haven't SQL logs !
Have I forgot something ? any ideas ?

**Edit :** Obviously, the problem is arquillian because it seems to work when I start the server, but not when the server is started by arquillian. any ideas ?

Comment: Did you restart the application-server after making changes to logger xml?

Comment: yes I did, because it is a unit test with arquilian

Comment: It seems to work when I start the server, but not when the server is started by arquillian

Comment: You should check, when you start the server by arquilian, is the xml file getting included in the classpath?

Comment: What xml file? For testing, everything I need is in the standalone.xml

Comment: If you want the console output to show the trace logging you also need to set the console-handler level to TRACE.

Comment: I have already set the level to TRACE in my standalone.xml, but no change